# In C++11 is there anyway to get the general template class from a template class with specified template arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits

*(e.g. get `std::list` from `std::list<some_value_type>`)*

Consider the following code:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>

std::string combine(int val, std::string str)
{
    return std::to_string(val) + str;
}

template <class T, class U>
auto foo(const T &container, const U &val)
    -> std::list<U>
{
    using RetType = std::list<U>;
    RetType result;

    for(auto item : container) {
        result.push_back(combine(item, val));
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::list<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::list<std::string> result = foo(numbers, std::string(" potato"));
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles, but I want it to work differently. I'd like `foo` to return the same kind of container as was passed into its first argument, but with its value type changed to that of the second argument, i.e. type `U`.

So if `foo` is passed in `std::list<int>` as its first argument and `std::string` as its second argument, it returns `std::list<std::string>`. Alternatively, if `foo` is passed in `std::vector<int>` as its first argument and `std::string` as its second argument, it returns `std:: vector<std::string>`. And so on.

Basically I want to replace both instances of `std::list<U>` with something that accomplishes the above, possibly using the facilities of `<type_traits>`.

Is there anyway to do this in C++11? The only solution I've found is to create overloaded versions of `foo` for every container type I want to use, but I'd much prefer if there was a general way to do it that covered all container types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a *template-template parameter* and change every occurrence of `list<T>` to a generic `C<T>`:

```
template <template<class...>class C, class T, class U>
auto 
foo(const C<T> &container, const U &val) -> C<U>
{
  using RetType = C<T>;
  // ...
}
```

An alternative which is commonly used is to use iterators which are a generic interface into the elements of a container. The standard algorithm that can be used is `std::transform`:

```
transform(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), inserter(result, result.begin()), [] (int n) {
  return combine(n, " potato");
});
```

Comment: This doesn't support custom allocators (or hashers/comparators etc. for `set`/`unordered_set`)

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could use ellipses when specifying a template-template class. Thanks!

Comment: @T.C. you are correct but for my purposes this is good enough. If I did need to use custom allocators, comparators, or hashers, I could overload `foo` using something like `template<class C, class T, class U, class V, class W> auto foo(const C<T, V, W> &container, const U &val) -> C<U, V, W>`. It would require allocators / comparators that could take either type, but I think it could be made to work.

Comment: @GuyGizmo "allocators ... that could take either type" do not exist; you have to rebind them.

Comment: @T.C. You are correct. I'm diving more into allocators now and I realize that what I said was nonsense.